# inverse_loading in WASCE 3.0.0.3 / Geronimo 3.0

Tags: apache, geronimo, ibm-was

I am trying to deploy a war onto a IBM Websphere Application Server Community Edition (WASCE) 3.0.0.3. I had some jars conflicting problems between those jars that comes with WASCE 3.0.0.3 and the jars comes from our application dependencies. At the end, I fixed the problem by using below property in geronimo-web.xml to force WASCE to load jars from my application.

`<import-package>!the.conflicting.jars</import-package>`

However, I would like to force WASCE to always take jars from my application first, i.e. inverse the default classloader behavior to load from application first. What is the correct config to change in this case?

---

After some searches, WASCE 3.0 is based on Geronimo 3.0 according to [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/wasce/V3.0.0/en/ce-framework.html). I found setting `<inverse-classloading>` in geronimo-web.xml may be helpful. But below two documents on [Apache Geronimo 3.0 website](http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC30/) mention that this function is no longer available on Geronimo 3.0

in [Migrating from G 2.x to G 3.x](http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC30/migrating-from-g-2x-to-g-3x.html), it says:

> **inverse-classloading** Geronimo 3.0 does not support the element in the deployment plan.

in [geronimo-web.xml](http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC30/geronimo-webxml.html),

> The `<sys:environment>` element contains the following elements:
>
> ...
>
> The `<inverse-classloading>` element can be used to specify that standard classloader delegation is to be reversed for this module. The Geronimo classloader delegation follows the Java EE 5 specifications, and the normal behavior is to load classes from a parent classloader (if available) before checking the current classloader. ...... ...... **(Not supported in 3.0, use `<import-package/>` instead)**

So if `<inverse-classloading>` is no longer available, what is the equivalent of this property in WASCE 3.0.0.3? Or how exactly should I do this using `<import-package/>` for all duplicated jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link you mentioned you will find the following section

> **`<sys:environment>`**
>
> The `<sys:environment>` XML element uses the Geronimo System namespace, which is used to specify the common elements for common libraries and module-scoped services, and is documented here:
>
> http://geronimo.apache.org/schemas-3.0/docs/geronimo-module-1.2.xsd.html
>
> The  element contains the following elements:
>
> The `<moduleId>` element is used to provide the configuration name for the web application as deployed in the Geronimo server. It contains elements for the groupId, artifactId, version and module type. Module IDs are normally printed with slashes between the four components, such as GroupID/ArtifactID/Version/Type.
>
> The `<dependencies>` element is used to provide the configurations and third party libraries on which the web module is dependent upon. These configurations and libraries are made available to the web module via the Geronimo classloader hierarchy.
>
> The `<bundle-activator>` element is used to create Bundle-Activator header in the manifest file of the web application. It specifies the entry point of the web application as deployed in the Geronimo server.
>
> The `<bundle-classPath>` element is used to create Import-Package header in the manifest file of the web application. It contains a list of directories or embedded jar files, which are also called bundle resources and extend the classpath of the web application.
>
> The `<import-package>` element is used to create Import-Package header in the manifest file of the web application. It specifies a list of packages to be resolved before the web application is started. Use `<import-package>!packagename</import-package>` to override the specific package in server.
>
> The `<export-package>` element is used to create Export-Package header in the manifest file of the web application. It specifies a list of packages to be exported.
>
> The `<require-bundle>` element is used create Require-Bundle header in the manifest file of the web application. It specifies a list of bundles to bind to regardless their packages.
>
> The `<dynamic-import-package>` element is used to create DynamicImport-Package header in the manifest file of the web application. It specifies a list of packaged to be imported dynamically, especially during class loading.

So basically, you need to add the following directive i.e

`<sys:import-package>!package-class-name-here*</sys:import-package>` within the `<sys:environment>` stanza. Typically before the Application Context-Root directive.

As you already know, this is in the geronimo-web.xml embedded in the Application WAR/EAR  -- as mentioned in the link

http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC30/geronimo-webxml.html

Comment: Thanks for your help, but does not exactly answer my question. what `<inverse-classloading>` does is always loading jars from web application level first then from WASCE, duplicated jars will not be loaded twice. The problem here is, if I need to use `<sys:import-package>!package-class-name-here*</sys:import-package>`, that means I need to know exactly which jars/packages not to import from WASCE server. and I probably need to add extra lines of this every time a new jar is introduced into my project, which is not very easy to maintain as well.

Comment: Though this is not exactly what I was asking for, at the end, this is what I did to fix the problem. It takes some time to identify all the duplicates, and may cause some problem in the future when introducing new jars.